# C++ Utf-16 Смайлики не выводятся

Tags: c++, windows

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
    _setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
    wcout << L"привет !" << endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Почему текст на разных языках выводится, а смайлики нет?

Comment: определите коды смайлов, посмотрите в шрифте, что находится по этим кодам

Comment: Смайлики относятся Supplementary code plain и в настоящей юникод кодировке UCS-2 не представимы. Представление UTF16 в виде суррогатных пар может и могло бы работать, но для этого необходима поддержка со стороны консоли и надлежащим образом выбранный шрифт.